# Meteor model popup not working

Tags: meteor

Meteor updated to 2.0 then .model is not working.Please help me.

```
var modal =  $("#loginRecruiter").modal();
modal.modal("show");
```

Comment: The class name is also .modal

Comment: meteor doesnt have a version 2.0 yet. Did you mean version 1.2?

Comment: Sorry its 1.2.0.1 @pahan

Comment: What library are you using for your modals?